# Is jCaptcha thread safe?

Tags: java, synchronization, storage, captcha

I'm using JCaptcha in a project and needed a behavior that was not directly available. so I looked into the source code to see if I can extend it to obtain what I want and found that the store implementation I use ([MapCaptchaStore](http://jcaptcha.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jcaptcha/trunk/jcaptcha/src/main/java/com/octo/captcha/service/captchastore/MapCaptchaStore.java?revision=460&view=markup)) uses a HashMap as the store... with no synchronization.

I know JCaptcha does not work in a clustered environment, it is not my case, but how about multiple clients at the same time? Is the store implementation synchronized externally or should I roll my own and make sure it is properly synchronized?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the reading source for MapCaptchaStore, this class is NOT thread-safe. I'm not 100% willing to stand behind this answer though, because synchronisation may be happening at a higher level (eg all accesses to a single instance of MapCaptchaStore may be synchronised on another object).

You could use another implementation of CaptchaStore. For example, EhcacheCaptchaStore

Answer (score 1):

Basic hashmap implementation of the captcha store is not synchronized, that could lead to some weird behaviour.
Other stores are thread safe, for a simple implementation use FastHashMapCaptchaStore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it is because it has been designed to be integrated with web applications which will always have multiple clients. It's also a CAPTCHA framework so they must have tested with both human and computer clients.

However, I would still recommend testing whether it behaves correctly in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: "Testing whether it behaves correctly in a multithreaded environment" is one of the great unsolved challenges of testing!